# Get rid of LLVM's Unconditional Branch

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Consider this IR:

```
label0:
  ret i32 0   
  br label %1
```

How do I get rid of the unconditional branch instruction? I have type casted it to `BranchInst` class and used `removeFromParent()` or `eraseFromParent()` but I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4BHT.png) error.

```
BranchInst *BI = dyn_cast<BranchInst>(i);
if(BI->isUnconditional())
  BI->removeFromParent();
```

Comment: You should include the error you see in your question.

Comment: I have added the error in the LLVM Error Link at the top.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a pass/transform that eliminates blocks with unconditional branches. See [`simplifycfg`](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#simplifycfg-simplify-the-cfg) (for the conditions) and the related [API](http://llvm.org/doxygen/SimplifyCFG_8cpp.html).

However, by ending up with two terminator instructions in your example basic block, I think you're probably trying to transform IR in some way.

If you check the documentation for [`BasicBlock`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html) it states:

> A well formed basic block is formed of a list of non-terminating
>   instructions followed by a single TerminatorInst instruction.

It's not clear how you end up with that basic block, but maybe after erasing the old terminator, you can use the `getTerminator` method; if it returns `nullptr` it means that the basic block is not well-formed.

I don't know how you do it ATM (the code you displayed is insufficient), but after erasing the old terminator, you can use the `Create()` method of the [`ReturnInst`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ReturnInst.html), the variant that takes a `BasicBlock` as a second argument to set up the new terminator instruction for you.

Comment: Got the solution . I was iterating the basic block using the for loop to delete the extra branch instruction . So I can't use it again in the I++ part of your for loop. I have to restructure the loop so that I increment before erasing the instruction.So ++I was required then BI->dropAllReferences() and finally BI->eraseFromParent().